# How to split an integer into a list of digits?

Tags: python

Suppose I have an input integer `12345`. How can I split it into a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

[Convert the number to a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) so you can iterate over it, then [convert each digit (character) back to an int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) inside a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [int(i) for i in str(12345)]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 117):

return array as string

```
>>> list(str(12345))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

return array as integer

```
>>> map(int,str(12345))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: In Python3, that would be `list(map(int,str(12345)))`

Comment: Or could also be `[*map(int,str(12345))]`

Answer (score 14):

I'd rather not turn an integer into a string, so here's the function I use for this:

```
def digitize(n, base=10):
    if n == 0:
        yield 0
    while n:
        n, d = divmod(n, base)
        yield d
```

Examples:

```
tuple(digitize(123456789)) == (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
tuple(digitize(0b1101110, 2)) == (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
tuple(digitize(0x123456789ABCDEF, 16)) == (15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

As you can see, this will yield digits from right to left. If you'd like the digits from left to right, you'll need to create a sequence out of it, then reverse it:

```
reversed(tuple(digitize(x)))
```

You can also use this function for base conversion as you split the integer. The following example splits a hexadecimal number into binary nibbles as tuples:

```
import itertools as it
tuple(it.zip_longest(*[digitize(0x123456789ABCDEF, 2)]*4, fillvalue=0)) == ((1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Note that this method doesn't handle decimals, but could be adapted to.

Comment: Small additional note for why this answer should be preferable over the accepted one is when you do things at scale, converting integer to string consumes more memory and will take longer time to calculate.

Answer (score 9):

```
[int(i) for i in str(number)]
```

or, if do not want to use a list comprehension or you want to use a base different from 10

```
from __future__ import division # for compatibility of // between Python 2 and 3
def digits(number, base=10):
    assert number >= 0
    if number == 0:
        return [0]
    l = []
    while number > 0:
        l.append(number % base)
        number = number // base
    return l
```

Comment: Good call, this was what I was about to write :)

Comment: @nd you can put the base of the number inside int like int(i,2) for binary see my post

Comment: This is a good answer, but would benefit from the use of `divmod`

Answer (score 4):

While `list(map(int, str(x)))` is the Pythonic approach, you can formulate logic to derive digits without any type conversion:

```
from math import log10

def digitize(x):
    n = int(log10(x))
    for i in range(n, -1, -1):
        factor = 10**i
        k = x // factor
        yield k
        x -= k * factor

res = list(digitize(5243))

[5, 2, 4, 3]
```

One benefit of a generator is you can feed seamlessly to `set`, `tuple`, `next`, etc, without any additional logic.

Answer (score 2):

like @nd says but using the built-in function of int to convert to a different base

```
>>> [ int(i,16) for i in '0123456789ABCDEF' ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

>>> [int(i,2) for i in "100 010 110 111".split()]
[4, 2, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` and `split` methods of strings:

```
>>> a=12345
>>> list(map(int,' '.join(str(a)).split()))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [int(i) for i in ' '.join(str(a)).split()]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Here we also use `map` or a list comprehension to get a list.

Comment: This is pointless. Joining a string with `' '` just adds spaces in between for the `.split`, so this is just a convoluted way to make a list of the characters (`list(str(a))` is much simpler) and more direct) - but there is also no reason to create that intermediate list anyway, since the string is already iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that does not involve converting to/from strings:

```py
from math import log10

def decompose(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    b = int(log10(n)) + 1
    return [(n // (10 ** i)) % 10 for i in reversed(range(b))]
```

Answer (score -1):

Strings are just as iterable as arrays, so just convert it to string:

```
str(12345)
```

Comment: OP wants `int`s not `str`ings

Answer (score -4):

Simply turn it into a string, split, and turn it back into an array integer:

```
nums = []
c = 12345
for i in str(c):
    l = i.split()[0]
    nums.append(l)
np.array(nums)
```

Comment: `i.split()[0]` is just `i` as `i` is a character from a string... And then your answer comes down to be the same as the ones posted 13 (!!!) years ago... And you still give a list of strings while the expected is a list of ints