# How to split integer and assigning parts to variables

Tags: python, variables, integer

I have been recently working on code that is a calculator. I know calculations can be done in the shell but that's no fun. Anyway, I have successfully been able to separate the numbers from the equation so that I can add them together. However it outputs like so:

Numbers: 22

This happens with the equation 2+2.

What I want to happen is it to take this integer (22) and separate it into 2 and 2 then assign those to variables "num1" and "num2" so that I can add them.

I have already tried:

```
[int(i) for i in str(Numbers)]
```

But the output is in a list and I have not found anything about taking a list item and assigning it to a variable.

I have looked at this:
[Splitting integer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python/1906727)

That is what got me my output above. I have also looked at this:
[Getting only element from a single-element list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161448/getting-only-element-from-a-single-element-list-in-python)

But I didn't understand that and don't have a high enough reputation score to comment and ask for explanation.

This is my current code as it currently stands:

```
var = input("Type equation:")

if " + " in var:
    nums = str(re.findall(r'\d',var))
    nums2 = nums.replace("['", "")
    nums3 = nums2.replace("', '", "")
    Numbers = nums3.replace("']", "")
    print(Numbers)
```

Comment: FYI, a dynamic number of variables is almost never a good idea. What's wrong with a list?

Comment: What is your input, your output and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the output is in a list and I have not found anything about taking a list item and assigning it to a variable.

Use access through index:

```
num1, num2 = [int(i) for i in str(Numbers)] [0], [int(i) for i in str(Numbers)] [1]
```

Comment: This redoes the same operation twice unnecessarily. Storing the result or using unpacking is a better idea.

Comment: Yes, to optimize that he can populate the list into a local variable and later access through index.

Comment: To simplify the code, simply do `num1, num2 = (int(i) for i in str(Numbers))`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your output to two variables num1, num2

`num1,num2=list(str(Numbers))`

Comment: You don't need the `list(str())`, `str()` is enough, i.e. `num1, num2 = str(Numbers)`. However, they will be strings, not integers.