# How do i convert split string to an array of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have a string that need to be spliced based on ,

```
x = '1,0.5,3'
y = x.split(',')
print(y)

//Result
//['1','0.5','3']
```

I would like to split the string but get an array of numbers as return value.

expected return

```
[1,0.5,3]
```

Comment: You may refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = '1,0.5,3'
l = [float(a) for a in x.split(',')]
```

Result:

```
[1,0.5,3]
```

Used `float()` since you have a floating point in there. You can use `int()` but that will do some rounding

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** need them to be **ints** instead of floats, you can truncate them for example:

```
>>> [int(float(e).__trunc__()) for e in x.split(",")]
[1, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert each item:

```
y = [float(y) for y in x.split(',')] // Result: [1.0, 0.5, 3.0]
```

Note: Using `int(y)` directly gave me this error due to the "0.5":

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.5'
```