# Write a program that one number consisting of THREE digits, separate the number into its individual digits

Tags: python

Write a program that prompts the user to enter one number consisting of THREE digits, separate the number into its individual digits and prints the digits separated from one another by a space and a comma. I made three individual digits into a list. And the except output should be no square brackets. Please help. Many Thanks!

```
input_integer = int(input("Enter three-digit integer: "))
s = [int(i) for i in str(input_integer)]

print("Digits in",input_integer, "are",s)
```

Here is what I except:

Enter three-digit integer: 123
Digits in 123 are 1, 2, 3

Comment: `input` gives a string. There's no reason to turn it to an `int` only to turn it back into a `string`. But you've close with what you have — you are missing a `join()` of some sort to put the list back together.

Comment: I think you want this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The brackets get printed because you have you are printing the entire list. Also you are swinging between `int` ant `str` somewhat unnecessarily. One way of printing only the digits is to join each element with a separator of your choice, e.g. `,`.

So one possible way to achieve what you want is (using f-string interpolation):

```py
number = input("Enter three-digit integer: ")
digits = list(number)

print(f"Digits in {number} are {', '.join(digits)}")
```

```
Enter three-digit integer: 123
Digits in 123 are 1, 2, 3
```