# How to split an interger in a list where the indexes have only one number in them?

Tags: python-3.x

**I mean something like this;**

```
        input:    x = 12345
        code:     y = magic(x)
              print(y)
        output:   (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I want to split the long interger in to many 1 length integers and put them in a list. Hopefully you guys can help

Comment: Does this help? `print([*map(int, str(x))])`

Comment: Yup it worked, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting integer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

> Quoted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-string-into-list-of-characters/

**Solution #1:** Using For loop

This approach uses for loop to convert each character into a list. Just enclosing the For loop within square brackets [] will split the characters of word into list.

```py
def split(word): 
    return [char for char in word]  

word = 'geeks'
print(split(word))
```

**Output:**

```py
['g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's']
```

**Solution #2:** Typecasting to list

Python provides direct typecasting of string into list using `list()`

```py
def split(word): 
    return list(word) 

word = 'geeks'
print(split(word))
```

**Output:**

```py
['g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's']
```