# Convert a number to an array of digits using a one line for loop in Python

Tags: python, append

I am trying t convert a number as follows:

input -> 123456
output -> ['1','2','3','4','5','6']

The following loop does work:

```
number = 123456
defg = []
abc = str(number)
for i in range(len(abc)):
    defg.append(abc[i])
```

However, when i try this in the form of a one line for loop, the output is `['None','None','None','None']`

My one line loop is as follows:

```
number = 123456
defg = []
abc = str(number)
defg= [[].append(abc[i]) for i in range(len(abc))]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above are concise, but I personally prefer vanilla list comprehension over `map`, as powerful as it is. I add this answer simply for the sake of adding diversity to the mix, showing that the same can be achieved without using `map`.

```
str_list = [abc[i] for i in range(len(abc))]
```

We can strive for a more Pythonic solution by avoiding direct indexing and using a simpler loop.

```
better_str_list = [char for char in abc]
```

This list comprehension is basically just a translation of the `for` loop you already have.

Comment: Thanks! This works well, but i was really hoping to understand what was going wrong with the one liner that i had written.

Comment: I have gained the insight i needed from your edited response. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped! I was just about to say, think of it this way: by appending an element in the original for loop, you're adding that element to the list. When we use list comprehension, we can directly reference what object we want to 'append' by simply stating it in the one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

here the solution

```
list(map(lambda x: str(x), str(number)))
```

```
Out[13]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

or you can do this

```
list(map(str, str(number)))                                                                                                                                                         
Out[13]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

or this

```
list(str(number))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

duplicate you can see more here
[Splitting integer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = 527876324

print(list(str(x))
```

Output

```
['5', '2', '7', '8', '7', '6', '3', '2', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

#### As your expection the result is

```
number = 123456
defg = []
abc = str(number)
[defg.append(abc[i]) for i in range(len(abc))]
print(defg)
```

When you run the loop the values are append to defg but it return none. you assign the None value to defg so it will show the `None` output

### Recomanded way

#### You can use list metnod to convert the number to list

```
number = 865393410
result = list(str(number))
print(result)
```

#### If you want int in list try this

```
number = 865393410
result = []
for i in list(str(number)):
    result.append(int(i))

print(result)
```

#### With single line loop

```
number = 865393410
result = []
[result.append(int(i)) for i in list(str(number))]
print(result)
```

> ### The last one is recommended for you

Comment: If you want more explanation [click here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append)

Comment: You can use last solution. it is batter answer.