# I wrote some code for find an armstrong number , I dont know why it doesnt give me false output?

Tags: python

A number that equals to the sum of its own digits, where each digit raised to the power of number of digits. For example, 153 is an armstrong number
because 1^3+3^3+5^3=153

at here user enters a number

```
    number=int(input("please enter a number: "))
```

Here in a while loop it puts the digits of the given number in numbers class

```
    numbers=[]
    while number>0:
        rem=number%10
        numbers.append(rem)
        number=int(number/10)
```

and then we want to put their qubes in qubes class

```
    qubes=[]
    for i in range(0,len(numbers)):
        c=(int(numbers[i]))**len(numbers)
        qubes.append(c)
```

and now we calculate the sum of the qubes class members

```
    result = sum(i for i in qubes)
```

I dont know why the if_code below doesnt work it just gives me false output I dont know why??

even when i enter 153 it prints false

```
    if result==number:
       print("true")
    else:print("false")
```

Comment: What value does `result` have and what do you expect it to have? Have you debugged why the value is different than what you expect?

Comment: So, does your program give you a `false` output, or no output?

Comment: Well, I guess if you input a number that is not armstrong it would output `"false"`, no?

Comment: What are "qubes"?

Comment: My guess is that it will output something but will take ages to do so

Comment: `(int(numbers[i]))**len(numbers)` raises the digits to the power of the number of digits, not to the power of 3. Also, the conversion to int here is unnecessary because they're already integers. Useful link: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/

Comment: btw: `number=int(number/10)` means you are going to lose your original `number`!

Comment: `number` no longer contains the value the user entered, because you assigned a new value to it on each iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: BTW, `sum(i for i in qubes)` is just a long way of saying `sum(qubes)`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi no  for example if its 1634 its like that 1^4+6^4+3^4+4^4

Comment: @quamrana doesnt matter if i dont write the else_code it gives me nothing

Comment: When I ran your code, I always got `false` printed out whatever number I entered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting integer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you are wrong. you should iterate over the integer not the iterator given by range function

Use this

```py
qubes=[]
for i in numbers:
  c=(int(i)**len(numbers))
  qubes.append(c)
```

instead of

```py
qubes=[]
for i in range(0,len(numbers)):
  c=(int(numbers[i]))**len(numbers)
  qubes.append(c)
```

Also you are referencing the number to itself `number=(int(number/10))` so your result value will be 153 but number value will be 0 at the end because you have reduced the value of number. So copy the value of number to another variable (num1 in below code).

Full code:

```py
number=int(input("please enter a number: "))
num1 = number
numbers=[]
while number>0:
    rem=number%10
    numbers.append(rem)
    number=int(number/10)
    
qubes=[]
for i in numbers:
  c=(int(i)**len(numbers))
  qubes.append(c)
result = sum(i for i in qubes)
print(result == int(num1))
```

Comment: I like your code better that that of the OP, however, both produce the same results less elegantly than some of the suggestions.

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes thanks for the comment, edited the post with full description

Answer (score 2):

To sum-up all suggestions from the comments:

Your main problem is:

- When you create the `numbers` list you use `number = int(number/10)`. ***This changes the `number` variable itself*** until it is equal to zero. This means that, as you experienced, `result == number` will always be `False`.

---

Some redundant parts of your code:

1. See [Splitting integer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python) to get a list of a number's digits. Most commonly you can just do `numbers = [int(i) for i in str(number)]`. This will actually solve the problem above as you don't change `number` this way.
2. The digits are already integers so no need for an `int` conversion. It is also more readable to use direct loop in Python rather than looping over indices:

   ```
   qubes = []
   for num in numbers:
       qubes.append(num**len(numbers))
   ```
3. `sum(i for i in qubes)` is just an overly explicit way of saying `sum(qubes)`.
4. You are printing either "true" or "false" according to a boolean result. There is no need for a condition and you can simply `print(result == number)`.

---

Putting together all the above, you can achieve this with a single line of code:

```
print(number == sum(int(digit)**len(str(number)) for digit in str(number)))
```